# Simple sitemap in html format as static block for Magento (/sitemap)

Tags: seo, sitemaps

we use a sitemap.xml and robots.txt to tell everyone where it is.

Now: we are looking for a human readible version of the sitemap - and want to print the contents of the complete sitemap file in html links as a list on a webpage (accessed through /sitemap per store view)

I was looking into widgets and static block calls and thought there must be an easy way to do this?

Does anyone have experiences with this?

Result is something like the image below

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already native to Magento for both categories and products.

Eg.

For categories, http://me-d1.sonassihosting.com/catalog/seo_sitemap/category/

For products, http://me-d1.sonassihosting.com/catalog/seo_sitemap/product/

Comment: thanks @Sonassi - if CMS pages could also be called then we would be complete. But this is a very good start!!

Comment: That's only a small modification to facilitate.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a static block, I usually use this extension: http://www.creare.co.uk/services/magento-seo-sitemap

This results in something like this on www.yoursite.com/sitemap:
[image]

Comment: Thanks _ I had seen that. Problem is that they have now integrated it into a whole SEO suite extension. And this extensions touches far too much elements that dont need touching .... but thanks - maybe the 'current' is an option

Comment: That's true.
You could always build your own Module and set the Frontpage to /sitemap with some code to output a sitemap - If you're not sure how to do that I'll edit my answer later today with some code :-)

Comment: Actually I was hoping for the last. And maybe the print command could just access the already available code to generate the XML sitemap ...

Comment: ps. for now installed creare btw (only we have limited categories, so it is quite empty)

Answer (score 0):

Building your static block by using a widget in default of Magento 2 is a good way. But the limitation of this method is relevant for small stores with a small amount of link of product or category pages. You definitely do it by manual. That's really waste a lot of time.

You should use this extension to get the result like something that you mentioned above. Generating HTML sitemap will help you do it by automatically in a few clicks. [HTML sitemap by BSS Commerce](https://bsscommerce.com/dynamic-html-sitemap-for-magento-2.html) is a solution for you

[image]